# Using ES6 import to import and use express router in single line

Tags: javascript, express, node-modules, es6-modules

What's the one line equivalent of below statement using ES6 Import

##### My existing code (using require)

```
app.use('/c', require('./route/routesc')); // routes which are common
app.use('/d', require('./route/routesd')); // routes for Data Agent
app.use('/a', require('./route/routesa')); // routes for Admin
```

##### Same code using ES6 Import

```
import routesc from "./route/routesc.js"
import routesd from "./route/routesd.js"
import routesa from "./route/routesa.js"

app.use('/c', routesc); // routes which are common
app.use('/d', routesd); // routes for Data Agent
app.use('/a', routesa); // routes for Admin
```

I am wondering is there any ONE liner for `import`?

FYI, I spent 40 mins searching for this answer and finally posted here on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ONE-*liner* equivalent would be

```
import routesc from "./route/routesc.js"; app.use('/c', routesc); // routes which are common
import routesd from "./route/routesd.js"; app.use('/d', routesd); // routes for Data Agent
import routesa from "./route/routesa.js"; app.use('/a', routesa); // routes for Admin
```

**There is no way** to combine them into a single statement, an `import` declaration always needs to stand on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `index.js` file with `export { routesc } from './routesc.js'` in your `/route` folder.

Then do `import * as routers from './route'`.

Now you can use it like `app.use('/c', routers.routesc);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) function. It will return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that will resolve to a [module namespace object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import#module_namespace_object) (same result as `import * as name from moduleName`).

Below is an example implementation. As `import` is an asynchronous function and `app.use()` doesn't accept promises, the [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) operator is used to return the fulfilment value (module namespace) instead of a Promise. This is then wrapped in brackets as `.default` needs to access the fulfilled value, not the Promise object.

```
app.use('/c', ( await import('./route/routesc.js') ).default ); // routes which are common
app.use('/d', ( await import('./route/routesd.js') ).default ); // routes for Data Agent
app.use('/a', ( await import('./route/routesa.js') ).default ); // routes for Admin
```

Going a little further, you could even implement your own `require` function. Just remember to add the `await` operator.

```
const require = async ( module ) => {
    return await import( module ).then( moduleNamespace => moduleNamespace.default );
}

app.use('/c', await require('./route/routesc')); // routes which are common
app.use('/d', await require('./route/routesd')); // routes for Data Agent
app.use('/a', await require('./route/routesa')); // routes for Admin
```